# i can't get opencv to work in android

Tags: android, eclipse, opencv, android-ndk

I'm using eclipse to write android programs and i can successfully run them on adt but recently i had to write a program that uses opencv but i can't get opencv to work with android i got ndk and add it to system variables and also downloaded opencv4android sdk from this link: http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/O4A_SDK.html and i imported all the examples now i get numerous error for any of the examples and when i click project->clean->clean all it comes up with following error :

> C:\Documentation_Android\android-ndk-r9d-windows-x86_64\android-ndk-r9d\ndk-build.cmd
>   Android NDK: WARNING:jni/Android.mk:mixed_sample: non-system libraries
>   in linker flags: -lopencv_java     Android NDK:     This is likely to
>   result in incorrect builds. Try using LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES
>   Android NDK:     or LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES instead to list the library
>   dependencies of the     Android NDK:     current module
>   [armeabi-v7a] Install        : libmixed_sample.so =>
>   libs/armeabi-v7a/libmixed_sample.so

I also tried Fix Project Properties but nothing happened and i tried to change jni/Application.mk and change armeabi-v7a to armeabi and that didn't helped too what should i do now ? is there anything I missing here ?

Comment: Do you really need to write with the NDK? The only reason I ask is I used OpenCV for Android for the first time a couple of weeks ago and was able to just use the SDK library. It was fairly easy to set up.

Comment: like @Squonk said, "15-puzzle", "color-blob-detection" and "image-manipulations" should work without any NDK support. try those first, then go fighting with jni/ndk.

Comment: I tried to use opencv4android sdk and it needed NDK to run. I didn't try anything just yet. If there is a way without NDK i will definitely go for it. can you provide the tutorial you used ?

Comment: @barak I can't run them too i think there is a problem with opencv library it has following errors : one in AsyncServiceHelper(import org.opencv.engine.OpenCVEngineInterface;) and another one in CameraBridgeView(import org.opencv.R;)

Comment: @odyse : It took me a while to find it but I think this is the guide I went through - just the first part that's titled "Application Development with Async Initialization" http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/dev_with_OCV_on_Android.html Basically you just need to create a library project from the OpenCV installation then make sure it is open and included as a library for your own Android Java project.

Answer (score 0):

have you added LOCAL_LDLIBS in android.mk file?

```
LOCAL_LDLIBS     := $(LOCAL_PATH)/jniLibs/libmixed_sample.so //path of .so file
```

Comment: i tried to change all android.mk files in opencv sdk directory and that didn't help too

Answer (score 0):

OK i found the answer ! How stupid I am ! i just have to go to opencv library project properties in android tab select project build target as android 4.2.2 and everything worked well